# Change text according to the text of the link

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my script:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var t = jQuery('.is-active').text().split(' ')[1];
        document.getElementById('pdm').innerHTML = t;
    });
</script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery(".mk-tabs-tab").click(function() {
            var t = jQuery('.is-active').text().split(' ')[1];
            document.getElementById('pdm').innerHTML = t;
        })
    });
</script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<h1 id="pdm" style="text-transform: capitalize !important; line-height:52px; word-spacing: 999px;" class="titolobianco"></h1>
<ul id="mk-tabs-tabs-3" class="mk-tabs-tabs">
    <li class="mk-tabs-tab is-active"><a href="#"> DISCLAIMER</a></li>
    <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#"> TERMS & CONDITIONS</a></li>
    <li class="mk-tabs-tab "><a href="#"> PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
    <li class="mk-tabs-tab "><a href="#"> PUBLIC REGULATORY</a></li>
    <li class="mk-tabs-tab "><a href="#"> REGISTER</a></li>
    <li class="mk-tabs-tab "><a href="#"> CONTACT SU</a></li>
    <div class="clearboth"></div>
</ul>
```

I Would when I click on `.mk-tabs-tab` class, display the link name in the h1 div, for example I click on `PRIVACY POLICY`, and display:

```
<h1 id="pdm" style="text-transform: capitalize !important; line-height:52px; word-spacing: 999px;" class="titolobianco">PRIVACY POLIC</h1>
```

My code work but display the previous link.
I click on

Comment: Either attach the click handler to each `a` inside your `li`s, or use `.text()` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, it looks like you need to do something like:

```
jQuery(".mk-tabs-tab").click(function() {
  jQuery('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
  jQuery(this).addClass('is-active');
  document.getElementById('pdm').innerHTML = jQuery(this).text().split(' ')[1];
})
```

In other words, you need to get the text from the link that was clicked and not necessarily the link that had the `is-active` class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to ever change the `is-active` class, and always get the first element

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var t   = $('.is-active').text().split(' ')[1];
  var pdm = $('#pdm').html(t);


  jQuery(".mk-tabs-tab").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('is-active').siblings().removeClass('is-active')
    var t = $(this).text().split(' ')[1];
    $('#pdm').html(t);
  });
});
```

```css
.is-active a {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="pdm" style="text-transform: capitalize !important; line-height:52px; word-spacing: 999px;" class="titolobianco"></h1>

<ul id="mk-tabs-tabs-3" class="mk-tabs-tabs">
  <li class="mk-tabs-tab is-active"><a href="#"> DISCLAIMER</a></li>
  <li class="mk-tabs-tab"><a href="#"> TERMS & CONDITIONS</a></li>
  <li class="mk-tabs-tab "><a href="#"> PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
  <li class="mk-tabs-tab "><a href="#"> PUBLIC REGULATORY</a></li>
  <li class="mk-tabs-tab "><a href="#"> REGISTER</a></li>
  <li class="mk-tabs-tab "><a href="#"> CONTACT SU</a></li>
  <div class="clearboth"></div>
</ul>
```